# Bright dark images detection

Tags: python, image-processing

I am doing a project about analysing the green trend of the trees. In term of initial processing, I've got intensity value for the whole 500 images and decided the threshold for selecting good images from the datasets. It's around from 60 to 122, and I named the range as good images.I also have detected some fog/haze images from the datasets with @ Andriy Makukha's help.

However, when I was trying to use the same method to distinguish good pictures and bad pictures in the different sense, it did not work at all. As you can see from the picuures below:[image: The average of intensity for images]

This is my code for the average of intensity and threshold:

```
 im = Image.open('IMAG0170.JPG')
 im_grey = im.convert('LA')
 width,height = im.size

 total=0
 for i in range(0,width):
   for j in range(0,height):
     total += im.getpixel((i,j))[0]

 mean = total / (width * height)
 print mean

import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

results = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in     os.walk("/Users/Terrynightbleach/Desktop/Dataset-Tree/No1_Leith Valley/"):
  for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith('.JPG')]:
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    avg_color_per_row = numpy.average(img, axis=0)
    avg_color = numpy.average(avg_color_per_row, axis=0)
    results.append(sum(avg_color/3))
np_results = np.array(results)
plt.hist(np_results,bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: The threshold for the sense]
In term of this site, it was really hard to decide the threshold.Are there any methods that I can use to distinguish the dark pictures with high intensity from the datasets?
If I was planing to focus on local variance and run a window approach, could some experts give me a hint on it. Thank you so much...

Comment: What is the "different sense" you are referring to?

Comment: Hi David, I mean different shooting places. some of images were taken from park, some were taken from other places.

Comment: Why do you presume that mean intensity of the red channel is a suitable measure to reject images? What are you looking for? Underexposed images?

Comment: @  Cris Luengo ， I did not presume the mean intensity of the red channel is a suitable one, I just calculated the mean intensity of the that three channels of the images, I 'm just looking for the method that can discard thoes totally dark images from the datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure exactly what you are looking for in a "good" image but I'll take a crack at it. I'm making some big assumptions here but it looks like all of those images come from some webcam that shoots the same location/view each time. If this one view is the only one you have to worry about, then I would leverage the fact that at night the bush is in the bottom 2/3 and the top 1/3 is essentially all black.

For a rough night/day filter, you could just check the top N rows before the bush starts and if they are really dark (close to, if not actually black) then you can toss the night images.

For the rest, I would again use the fact that these are plants and the pixels green channels will be much more useful. i.e. some calculation to check how much larger the G value is than R & B values could be really helpful.

Comment: Extract the image pixel array
- Scan through the array using 64x64 windows; for each window, calculate the texture features, store them into arrays
- Study the histogram(s) you obtained from the image feature array(s)
- Find a way to differentiate foggy images from normal ones.